# How to center images within a div using Skeleton Boilerplate

Tags: css, css-position, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm using the Skeleton boilerplate along with masonry.js to create an image gallery. The problem I'm having is that all the images are pushed to the left and I have a significant amount of space on the right, which is making my gallery look way off center. I have tried everything I can think of to fix this, but it just won't budge... I'm also relatively new to web design so that isn't helping matters :). someone please tell me how to center the images in the div.

*I solved this on my own months ago. The problem was caused by the skeleton framework. Once I removed skeleton everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot or link to your page.

Comment: Sure, I am using a screenshot of my site in Dreamweaver. http://imgur.com/8oBTJcE

Comment: How about previewing the page in browser? It might be that Dreamweaver is a bit rusty from the browser engine perspective :)

Answer (score 1):

What i can notice at first glance is that you are using **9** columns in a **12** columns based  grid.

According to [Skeleton documentation](http://getskeleton.com/), "The grid is a 12-column fluid grid with a max width of 960px".

So you should either add additional column in your layout, or change the class of the three columns to be

```
<div class="four columns portfolio">
```

Comment: have you updated the css as well? The CSS selector should be **four.columns.portfolio** in order to take effect now.

Comment: In that case, and with regards to the uploaded screenshots, i would guess that the problem is caused by the **"margin: auto;"** rule. try the image centering rule on the images itself, and not on the container divs.